# Let $X$ be $S^1$ with its diameter, and let $Y=X/\sim$ with the antipodal relation. I'm going to apply SVK ...

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider $X$ the space $S^1$ with its diameter. Consider $Y=X/\sim$ with the antipodal relation. I'm going to apply SVK.

i) Let $p \in Y$ be in the circle. Consider $U = Y \setminus \{p\}$. This space can be deformed into the diameter with the antipodal action. Therefore, $S^1$ (diameter/$\sim$) is a deformation retract of $U$. $\pi_1 U \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

ii) Let $q\in Y$ be the center of the diameter. Let $V = Y \setminus \{q\}$. This space is homotopy eq to $S^1/\sim$, that is, $S^1$.

iii) $U \cap V$ is arc-connected and contractible.

By SVK: $$\pi_1Y = \mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: 1) Neither $U$ or $V$ is contractible. The diameter forms a loop under the antipodal identification. 2) $U \cap V$ doesn't look connected to me.

Comment: Yes. You're right. What kind of open sets may I choose?

Comment: How about first deleting a point on the circle, and then second deleting a point on the diameter?

Comment: I changed it. Do you approve it?

Comment: Approve? Heh, i don't think that's up to me But I do think what you've written is true now. I will also say that it's a little short on details. For example, the key realization for me was that your space $Y$ is just $S^1 \vee S^1$. If your reader hadn't realized that, I'm not sure they could follow all your arguments.

Comment: hahahaha sure, but with draws everything is easier

Comment: If that means you're including drawings in your final write-up, but they are too much trouble to include in posting the question to math.stackexchange, I am 100% with you. Good luck!